# How to check record is fully empty on left join in jooq query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, dsl, jooq

I try to fetch a record from table with left join on another table. An information in the second table can be not found but I expect an information from the first table.

```
    val citizenship = Tables.COUNTRIES.`as`("citizenship")
    try {
        return context.selectFrom(Tables.CLIENT_PROJECTIONS
                .leftJoin(citizenship).on(
                        Tables.CLIENT_PROJECTIONS.CITIZENSHIP_COUNTRY_CODE.eq(
                                citizenship.CODE_ALPHA2
                        )
                )
        ).where(Tables.CLIENT_PROJECTIONS.ID.eq(id)).fetchOne {
            val clientProjection = ClientProjectionMapper.map(it.into(Tables.CLIENT_PROJECTIONS)) ?: return@fetchOne null
            clientProjection.citizenship = CountryMapper.map(it.into(citizenship))
            clientProjection
        }
    } catch (ex: DataAccessException) {
        logger.error("Failed to access to database", ex)
        throw ex
    }
```

I convert data from CountriesRecord to Entity in `CountryMapper`:

```
object CountryMapper : RecordMapper<CountriesRecord, Country> {
  override fun map(record: CountriesRecord?): Country? = when {
    record != null -> {
        Country(
                countryCode = record.codeAlpha,
                title = record.title
        )
    }
    else -> {
        null
    }
  }
}
```

But if query returns null in every fields of `CountriesRecord` my `map` method receive a non-nullable entity but everyone fields of this entity is empty.

I can check every field of `CountriesRecord` is it null but i think that isn't good idea. Can I check it by another more best way? May be I should write more correct query to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` in SQL does exactly that. It produces nulls for all columns of the left joined table for which there was no match in the join's `ON` clause.

You don't have to check whether each column is null. The primary key will be good enough, because that should have a `NOT NULL` constraint on it, meaning that if the primary key value is null (`record.codeAlpha`), then that must be because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Change your second mapper to this:

```kotlin
object CountryMapper : RecordMapper<CountriesRecord, Country> {
  override fun map(record: CountriesRecord?): Country? = when {
    record?.codeAlpha != null -> {
      Country(
        countryCode = record.codeAlpha,
        title = record.title
      )
    }
    else -> {
      null
    }
  }
}
```